# NSPortTimeoutException while using Distributed Object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, gnustep

I am using distributed object for inter process communication. I am running one server and four instance of client but i am getting NSPortTimeoutException. I want to store client object @server for further communication between clients.
//client code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

ClientCode *client = [[ClientCode alloc] init];

/* Get the proxy */
id <myProtocol> proxy = (id <myProtocol>)[NSConnection rootProxyForConnectionWithRegisteredName: @"DirectoryServer" host:nil usingNameServer: [NSSocketPortNameServer sharedInstance]];

if ([proxy conformsToProtocol:@protocol(myProtocol)]) {
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"NO");
}

NSString *recDataFromServer = [proxy print: client];
NSLog(@"%@", recDataFromServer);
/* Release the pool */
[pool release]
return 0;
}

@protocol myProtocol
-(NSString *)print : (id)client;
@end
@interface ClientCode : NSObject {


}
@end
@implementation ClientCode

-(void)startClient
{
NSLog(@"server called me");
}
@end
```

server Code

```
@interface printHello : NSObject <myProtocol>{
NSMutableArray *saveClassObject;
}
@end

@implementation printHello


- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    saveClassObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return self;
}

-(NSString *)print : (bycopy id)client
{   
[saveClassObject addObject: client];
//NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([client class]));

NSLog(@"client calling.....");
[client startClient];
NSLog(@"%@", saveClassObject);
return @"parag";
}


-(void)recieveMessage
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startObserver) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
[pool release];
}

-(void)startObserver
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

printHello *telephoneDirectory= [[printHello alloc] init];

/*
 * Create a new socket port for your connection.
 */
NSSocketPort *port = [NSSocketPort port];

NSLog(@"%d", [port isValid]);
/*
 * Create a connection using the socket port.
 */
NSConnection *connXion = [NSConnection connectionWithReceivePort: port
                                                        sendPort: port];
/*
 * Set the responding server object as
 * the root object for this connection.
 */
[connXion setRootObject: telephoneDirectory];

/*
 * Try to register a name for the NSConnection,
 * and report an error if this is not possible.
 */
if ([connXion registerName: @"DirectoryServer"
            withNameServer: [NSSocketPortNameServer sharedInstance]] == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"Unable to register as 'DirectoryServer'");
    NSLog(@"Perhaps another copy of this program is running?");
    exit(1);
}

/* Start the current runloop. */
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

[telephoneDirectory release];
/* Release the pool */
[pool release];
return 0;

}
```

Output @client

```
2011-10-11 20:50:35.415 client[54606:903] called
2011-10-11 20:50:35.424 client[54606:903] (null)
2011-10-11 20:50:35.420 client[54608:903] called
2011-10-11 20:50:35.425 client[54608:903] (null)
2011-10-11 20:50:35.424 client[54607:903] called
2011-10-11 20:50:35.428 client[54607:903] (null)
2011-10-11 20:50:35.434 client[54609:903] called
2011-10-11 20:50:35.437 client[54609:903] (null)
2011-10-11 20:50:36.091 client[54606:903] YES
2011-10-11 20:50:36.093 client[54609:903] YES
2011-10-11 20:50:36.093 client[54607:903] YES
2011-10-11 20:50:36.094 client[54608:903] YES
2011-10-11 20:50:36.098 client[54606:903] server called me
2011-10-11 20:50:36.103 client[54608:903] server called me
2011-10-11 20:50:36.117 client[54608:903] parag
2011-10-11 20:50:36.119 client[54609:903] server called me
2011-10-11 20:50:36.125 client[54607:903] server called me
2011-10-11 20:50:36.127 client[54606:903] parag
2011-10-11 20:50:36.125 client[54609:903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSPortTimeoutException', reason: '[NOTE: this exception originated in the server.]
[NSPortCoder sendBeforeTime:sendReplyPort:] timed out (10340039236.124821 340039236.124922) 1'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff825487b4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff84d95f03 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   Foundation                          0x00007fff86416483 -[NSConnection sendInvocation:internal:] + 4304
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8251a98c ___forwarding___ + 860
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82516a68 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
    5   client                              0x0000000100000d4f main + 307
    6   client                              0x0000000100000c14 start + 52
    7   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

Output @server

```
2011-10-11 20:50:36.095 DistributedServer[54579:1303] client calling.....
2011-10-11 20:50:36.098 DistributedServer[54579:1303] client calling.....
2011-10-11 20:50:36.100 DistributedServer[54579:1303] client calling.....
2011-10-11 20:50:36.102 DistributedServer[54579:1303] client calling.....
2011-10-11 20:50:36.115 DistributedServer[54579:1303] (
    "<ClientCode: 0x100111250>",
    "<ClientCode: 0x100111250>",
    "<ClientCode: 0x100111250>",
    "<ClientCode: 0x100111250>"
)
```

When I am running client second time i getting output at client console but i am getting nothing at server console.

client output second time

```
2011-10-11 20:53:54.514 client[54801:903] called
2011-10-11 20:53:54.518 client[54801:903] (null)
2011-10-11 20:53:54.521 client[54800:903] called
2011-10-11 20:53:54.526 client[54800:903] (null)
2011-10-11 20:53:54.516 client[54804:903] called
2011-10-11 20:53:54.526 client[54804:903] (null)
2011-10-11 20:53:54.529 client[54803:903] called
2011-10-11 20:53:54.533 client[54803:903] (null)
2011-10-11 20:53:54.955 client[54803:903] YES
2011-10-11 20:53:54.956 client[54800:903] YES
2011-10-11 20:53:54.956 client[54801:903] YES
2011-10-11 20:53:54.956 client[54804:903] YES
2011-10-11 20:53:54.961 client[54804:903] server called me
2011-10-11 20:53:54.963 client[54801:903] server called me
2011-10-11 20:53:54.964 client[54801:903] parag
2011-10-11 20:53:54.965 client[54800:903] server called me
2011-10-11 20:53:54.966 client[54800:903] parag
2011-10-11 20:53:54.966 client[54804:903] parag
2011-10-11 20:53:54.969 client[54803:903] server called me
2011-10-11 20:53:54.970 client[54803:903] parag
```

Any idea on how to fix NSPortTimeoutException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSPortTimeoutException` was coming because i was saving object of client @server and not removing that object after termination of client. Now my code is working fine.